# SQL to count table column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a single table as shown below:

```
ID | Name | Category
--------------------
1  | Cat  | Mammal
2  | Dog  | Mammal
3  | Pea  | Vegetable
4  | Snake| Reptile
```

I would like an SQL query that will list each individual item with the count of the elements in its category. i.e.

```
Name  | Count of Category
-------------------------
Cat   | 2
Dog   | 2
Pea   | 1
Snake | 1
```

Edit1: I am using postgrsql

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DBMS support window function, we can try to use `COUNT` window function and add each individual item in `PARTITION BY`

```
SELECT Name,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Category)
FROM T
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d42a32664d68b6e6fec3a9a6cdbfd6d6)

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would also prefer a window function like D-Shih showed. If your DB doesn't support this, you can use a subquery to count the category, something like this:

```
SELECT name, c "Count of Category" FROM
yourtable y JOIN
(SELECT category, COUNT(category) c FROM yourtable GROUP BY category) sub
ON y.category = sub.category;
```

This will produce the identic outcome.

Comment: There is a single table with a single aggregate to compute, there is no need for JOIN and subquery.

Comment: Feel free to show a better option